# Breadcrumb and Multi-category PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, navigation, content-management-system, breadcrumbs

My site, use a multi-category system with the following structure:

1. Products URL: /products/ (index of all the products)
2. Category URL: /products/indoor/ (product index within the category)
3. Category URL: /products/outdoor/ (product index within the category)
4. Single product URL: **/products/tile/**

The **TILE** product is present in indoor category and outdoor category

My problem is related to navigation.
If the user navigates the INDOOR category and then goes to the TILE page, after landing in the individual product page I can not create a correct breadcrumbs.

Any ideas for a feature, or a better logic or graphic solution?

Comment: Why can't you create the correct breadcrumbs? Elaborate? On a separate note, is there a reason why you don't separate products and categories? For example, categories under `/category/...` and products under `/product/...`.

Comment: For my site browsing the product page would be the catalog page. The catalog is divided into two category for ex: Indoor and Outdoor. TILE a product must be both category. My CMS has the breadcrumbs function. But when I'm on /prodocts/tile/ page, I create the breadcrumb **poducts > indoor** or **products > outdoor**? This is my problem

Comment: It sounds like this is an opinionated problem, which although legitimate, would be too broad for this community.